# Java : Rename MultiPartFile with unique name and store it to a folder and save the url to database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

i have a Backend based on Spring Boot, the frontend based on Angular 5.
after recieving the MultiPartFile via Angular i want to rename this file with 
unique name(id of the table) and store the file into folder then put the URL of this file to DataBase PostgreSQL.
please help me, i tested a lot of methods without any good result. 
i tryed to convert the MultiPartFile to File, but i don't know how to do. 
please help me

#### Here is the Class that contain the methods of handling MultiPartFile :

```
package smart.syndic.metier;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.FileSystemUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Service
public class StorageService 
{
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
private final Path rootLocation = Paths.get("fichiers/prestataires");

public void store(MultipartFile file) {
    try {

        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), 
this.rootLocation.resolve(file.getOriginalFilename()), 
StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("FAIL!");
    }
 }

public Resource loadFile(String filename) {
    try {
        Path file = rootLocation.resolve(filename);
        Resource resource = new UrlResource(file.toUri());
        if (resource.exists() || resource.isReadable()) {
            return resource;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("FAIL!");
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("FAIL!");
    }
 }

public void deleteAll() {
    FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(rootLocation.toFile());
 }
}
```

#### Here is the RestController :

```
package smart.syndic.web;

import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;


import  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.
MvcUriComponentsBuilder;
import smart.syndic.dao.PrestatairesRepository;
import smart.syndic.dao.PrestatairesTypesRepository;
import smart.syndic.entities.Prestataires;
import smart.syndic.metier.StorageService;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class PrestatairesRestController 
{
@Autowired
private PrestatairesRepository repository;

@Autowired
private PrestatairesTypesRepository repository2;

@Autowired
private StorageService storageService;

private List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

@RequestMapping(value="/prestataires/{id}", 
        method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Prestataires getVilles(@PathVariable Long id)
{
    return repository.findOne(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/prestataires", 
        method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Prestataires addVilles(Prestataires p,
        @RequestParam("multipartFile") MultipartFile file)
{
    try{
        storageService.store(file);
        files.add(file.getOriginalFilename());
        p.setPhoto("fichiers/prestataires/"+file.getOriginalFilename());

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


 p.setPrestatairesTypes(repository2.findOne(p.getPrestatairesTypes()
 .getId()));

    return repository.save(p);              
}

}
```

#### Here is the Entity Prestataires :

```
package smart.syndic.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Prestataires implements Serializable 
{
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String nom;
private String email;
private String tele;
private String fax;
private String rib;
private String adresse;
private String taches;
private String photo;

//-------------------Constructors--------------------
//-------------------Getters and Setters--------------------


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_PRESTATAIRES_TYPES")
private PrestatairesTypes prestatairesTypes;
}
```

Comment: what is the issue with your current code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If filename is only the issue, your code is fine all you need to is create filename using some string or just clean it like below

```
//Create custom filename 
String filename = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
//remove spaces and make lowercase    
filename = filename.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "-");
```

or

```
String filename = p.getId()+"."+file.getOriginalFilename().substring(file.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```

And then in your copy method

```
Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), this.rootLocation.resolve(filename),
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Here is example

```
@Service
public class UploadService {

@Value("${app.image.cdn}")
private String imageCDN;

@Value("${app.upload.path}")
private String uploadPath;

private Path rootLocation;


public String store(MultipartFile file) {

    String storedLocation;
    rootLocation = Paths.get(uploadPath);

    String filename = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
    filename = filename.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "-");

    try {
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            throw new StorageException("Failed to store empty file " + filename);
        }
        if (filename.contains("..")) {
            // This is a security check
            throw new StorageException(
                    "Cannot store file with relative path outside current directory "
                            + filename);
        }
        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), this.rootLocation.resolve(filename),
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        storedLocation = imageCDN+filename;

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new StorageException("Failed to store file " + filename, e);
    }


    return storedLocation;
}
}
```

And your application.properties

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=20MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=20MB

app.upload.path=/uploads
app.image.cdn=http://yourhost.com/uploads/
```

And your StorageException class

```
public class StorageException extends RuntimeException {

  public StorageException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }

  public StorageException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. i want to rename the MultiPartFile with unique name(the id of the row in the table)id of Prestataires before storing it to folder. than save the URL of the File into DataBase. Something like this  file.renameTo(String.valueOf(p.getId())). p is an instance of Prestataires.

Comment: @beyyatoabdellah - rename is another option. Why not create the right name in the first instance. Check updated answer.

Comment: i will try this and i will inform you of the result. thanks sir.

Comment: i have this Error in backend :   smart.syndic.metier.StorageException: Failed to store file null.png   Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \uploads\null.png. i think the probleme of null is the file is renamed with id of Prestataires that null because it will be generated in the moment of respository.save(p); so it was null before this operation. Also i want to have no just one folder for saving files, i want to have more than one.

Comment: yes, fix null id and for the multiple directories just create folder and change filename accordingly.

Comment: Could you please continue Helping me. where should i create the other directories, and how to fix null id?

Comment: i solved the problem, thanks for your Help, i will share the new code.

Comment: Will this method affect to the file extension?

Answer (score 1):

#### Here is the RestController

```
package smart.syndic.web;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
 import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder;
import smart.syndic.dao.PrestatairesRepository;
import smart.syndic.dao.PrestatairesTypesRepository;
import smart.syndic.entities.Prestataires;
import smart.syndic.metier.StorageService;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class PrestatairesRestController 
{
@Autowired
private PrestatairesRepository repository;

@Autowired
private PrestatairesTypesRepository repository2;

@Autowired
private StorageService storageService;

private List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

@RequestMapping(value="/prestataires/{id}", 
        method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Prestataires getVilles(@PathVariable Long id)
{
    return repository.findOne(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/prestataires", 
        method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Prestataires addVilles(Prestataires p,
        @RequestParam("multipartFile") MultipartFile file)
{
    Prestataires pp = null;
    try{
        pp = repository.save(p);
        storageService.store(file, "prestataires",pp);
        files.add(file.getOriginalFilename());


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    p.setPrestatairesTypes(repository2.findOne(p.getPrestatairesTypes().getId()));
    updateVilles(p.getId(), p);
    return pp;              
}

@RequestMapping(value="/prestataires/{id}", 
        method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public Prestataires updateVilles(
        @PathVariable Long id,
        @RequestBody Prestataires v)
{

    v.setId(id);
    return repository.save(v);
}
}
```

#### The StorageService

```
package smart.syndic.metier;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.FileSystemUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import smart.syndic.entities.Prestataires;

@Service
public class StorageService 
{
private String imageCDN = "http://www.yourHost.com/fichiers/";

private Path rootLocation;

public String store(MultipartFile file, String chemin, Prestataires p) {
    String storedLocation = null;
    rootLocation = Paths.get("fichiers/"+chemin+"/");
    String filename = null;

    filename = p.getId()+"."+file.getOriginalFilename()
    .substring(
            file.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);


    try {
        if(file.isEmpty()){
            throw new StorageException("Failed to store Empty"
                    + " File "+filename);
        }
        if(filename.contains(".."))
        {
            throw new StorageException("Cannot store file with relative path "
                    + "outside current directory "+filename);
        }

        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), this.rootLocation.resolve(filename), 
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        storedLocation = imageCDN + filename;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new StorageException("Failed to store file " + filename, e);
    }
    p.setPhoto("fichiers/"+chemin+"/"+filename);
    return storedLocation;
}

public Resource loadFile(String filename) {
    try {
        Path file = rootLocation.resolve(filename);
        Resource resource = new UrlResource(file.toUri());
        if (resource.exists() || resource.isReadable()) {
            return resource;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("FAIL!");
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("FAIL!");
    }
}

public void deleteAll() {
    FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(rootLocation.toFile());
}
}
```

#### The other Classes didn't have a change including the frontEnd

Comment: getting error while testing api in postman like this "Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile'.please help me to fix this error @beyyatoabdellah